# Getter functions

Tags: javascript, getter

I've peeked into many plugins' code (for educational purposes) and basically every one of them (which deals with prototypes), has bunch of functions like this:

```
myMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {

    return this.latlng; 
};

//OR

myMarker.prototype.getObject = function() {

    return this;
};
```

What's the reason behind this?

Why not just to use `someObject.latlng` instead of `someObject.getPosition()`?

Comment: this.latlng may be a private property of the object so that you are restricted to change this property.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com: There is no such thing like a "private property" in JavaScript.

Comment: Why don't you ask the developers who invented it? If they say `latlng` is unreadable, slap their faces off.

Comment: Perhaps one may want to restrict access to the object variables and allow access only via getter setter methods?Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common reason for doing this is to avoid coupling the object's internal data storage to the API; in this example you could change the way the position is stored internally, and then add some processing to `getPosition()` to return a backwards compatible result.

For example, version 1.1 of this library might look like this, and calling code wouldn't need to be changed:

```
myMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
    return this.latitude + this.longitude; 
};
```

It is possible to accomplish this using computed properties with ES5 [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), but only if the code doesn't need to run on Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

When you say like this.

```
myMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {

    return this.latlng; 
};
```

You are defining function `getPosition` which available to all instance to class `myMarker`.

So,all object of this class share this method without replication.

For `someObject.latlng`,there is nothing wrong.
But assume, this object is accessible to all which are in the current scope.So,it can be modified/accessible to anyone.

When you go through prototype you are trying to define some pattern,which gives restriction for access and modification of property